# Convert bitdepth of png image

Tags: matlab, png, grayscale, bit-depth

How to convert the image with the following information:
ColorType: truecolor
Format: png
bitDepth: 24

to a png grayscale image with bitdepth=8 in matlab ?

Comment: By convert, you mean create a new file ? How do you want to manage the extra bits, by truncation or by mapping the grey ranges ?

Comment: i tried to use imwrite(I2,nom_fich,'BitDepth',8); but e the image is always 24 bits: no change

Comment: Ok, but can you answer the questions in the comment ?

Comment: the method that will preserve as much quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for `imwrite`

> For color images, the BitDepth value is the number of bits per plane

You ask matlab to write 3 colour channels with 8 bits each, which results in 24 bits. If you want grayscale, use `rgb2gray` first to convert to grayscale, then write.